# How do I prevent deleting reference entities/tables using the JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jparepository

I'm creating a delete api endpoint for my spring boot application. I tried using the delete() and deleteById() methods provided by the JpaRepository. However, whenever I try to delete a concert, using the ConcertEntity or the concertId, the venue entry associated is deleted from the Venues table. How do I prevent deleting reference entities/tables using the JpaRepository?

My current solution is to set the venue to null before deleting the concert entity. My concertRepositroy extends to JpaRepository.

## Current Solution in Service Impl

```
public void deleteConcert(ConcertEntity e){
  e.setVenue(null);
  this.concertRepository.delete(e);
}
```

## Concert Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONCERTS")
public class ConcertEntity{

  @Id
  private UUID concertId;

  @Column(name = "ARTIST")
  String artist;

  @Column(name = "VENUE_ID")
  VenueEntity venue;


  /*Getters && Setters here...*/
}
```

Comment: if you want to delete only entity, that you want instead of related entity, you can't use cascade all. otherwise cascade all tells hibernate that delete merge insert etc. do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proper annotation to define the relationship (@ManyToOne or @OneToOne)

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "VENUE_ID")
private VenueEntity venue;
```

That should not trigger any cascade deletion by default, but you can add the cascade parameter to the @ManyToOne or @OneToOne annotation if you want to customize the behavior.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! But what exactly is optional = true?

Comment: @milo you can remove it if you want as true is the default value for the optional parameter. Optional = true means the foreign key will be nullable, optional = false means the foreign key will be not null.